# TypeError: str.replace is not a function

Tags: reactjs, build, digital-ocean

I have a problem with my server in digital ocean.
When I run `npm run build`, I get this error message.

<--- JS stacktrace --->

> FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
> out of memory  1: 0xb09c10 node::Abort()
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]  2: 0xa1c193
> node::FatalError(char const*, char const*)
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]  3: 0xcf8dbe
> v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool)
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]  4: 0xcf9137
> v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char
> const*, bool) [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]
> 5: 0xeb09d5  [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]
> 6: 0xec069d
> v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace,
> v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags)
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]  7: 0xec339e
> v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin,
> v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]  8: 0xe84612
> v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType,
> v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]  9: 0xe7cc24
> v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawWithImmortalMap(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::Map,
> v8::internal::AllocationAlignment)
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node] 10: 0xe7ec81
> v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewRawTwoByteString(int,
> v8::internal::AllocationType)
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node] 11: 0x121c9e9
> v8::internal::Runtime_StringBuilderConcat(int, unsigned long*,
> v8::internal::Isolate*)
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node] 12: 0x15f2099
> [/home/andifaizal/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.0/bin/node]

How can I fix this? I use the server ubuntu in digital ocean.